# Drawing function in tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have to draw function with `\plot` but it says "Dimension too large", this is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=major, xmin=0, xmax=3, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$x(t), y(t)$, scale=0.3]

\plot[blue] plot[samples=100, smooth] expression{(1 + 2 * x)*exp(-2*x) * sin(280* 3.14 * x)};

\plot[red, dashed] plot[samples=100, smooth] expression{ (1+2*x) * exp(-2*x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Hope you can help me because I need it in few days, there are picture how it should look:

[image]

and this are functions:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try instead `min`, `max` values defined function domain like follows:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=8cm,
 domain=0:4, samples=200, 
 xlabel={$t$}, ylabel={$x(t), y(t)$},
    grid]
\addplot[red,smooth]    {(1 + 2*x)*exp(-2*x)*sin(280*3.14*x)};
\addplot[smooth,dashed] {+(1+2*x)*exp(-2*x)};
\addplot[smooth,dashed] {-(1+2*x)*exp(-2*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me an error `! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.12' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors`. Does the `compat` command depend on the version of pgf plots installed ?
`compat=1.9` works though.

Comment: @AJN, for sake of safety, check your version of `pgfplots`. I have installed 1.12.1. Recent version is 1.13  from 2016-01-06.  Your MWE cause error at me too. It is worth upgrade pgfplots.

Comment: Thanks, My `pgfplots` version is 1.9. (I'm using Ubuntu's texlive package instead of texlive's `tlmgr`. Haven't gotten around to installing latest texlive.